# How to access certain instance of AngularJS controller (AS-syntax) in a unit test?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I am writing an integration test for a group of Angular directives.
Each directive validates one or many fields. For example, for Red and Blue fields to be valid, both of them need to be checked.

The full code (with the non-test part) is available [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nikoudel/s1a046qb/).

The problem is that inside the unit test I don't know how to access that particular instance of the MainController affected by the validation directives:

```
var html = "" +
"<form ng-controller='MainController as main'>" +
"    <input type='checkbox' ng-model='main.red' red-validator='main'>" +
"    <input type='checkbox' ng-model='main.blue' blue-validator='main'>" +
"</form>"

describe('validator directives', function(){

  beforeEach(function(){
    module('myApp', function($controllerProvider){
        $controllerProvider.register('MainController', MainController);
    });
  });

  it('validate and invalidate fields', function(){
    inject(function($controller, $compile, $rootScope){
        var scope = $rootScope.$new();
      var element = $compile(html)(scope);
      var target = $controller('MainController');

      scope.$apply(function(){
        target.red = true;
        target.blue = true;
      });

      expect(target.redIsValid).toBe(true);
      expect(target.blueIsValid).toBe(true);

      scope.$apply(function(){
        target.red = false;
      });

      expect(target.redIsValid).toBe(false);
      expect(target.blueIsValid).toBe(false);
    });
  });
});
```

$controller('MainController') constructs a new instance, so the test fails because it isn't setting neither it is reading the values from a correct instance. Is there some way to get that particular instance?

PS. I'd like to avoid moving controller properties to $scope just to make tests work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller instance may be retrieved with

```
var ctrl = html.controller('ngController');
```

Comment: Yes, I stand corrected, it may require `var ctrlScope = element.scope()` for inherited scope, not really cleaner than getting an instance.